# TYPO3 get page resources in Fluid Template

Tags: typo3

I am currently trying to access the images I uploaded to my page resources in my fluid template. But I can't make them appear in the frontend.

I have tried the following 2 approaches:

```
    <f:if condition="{files}">
      <f:then>
        <f:for each="{files}" as="image">
          <f:uri.image image="{image}" />
        </f:for>
      </f:then>
    </f:if>
```

and with vhs viewhelpers:

```
<v:page.resources.fal
        table="pages"
        field="media"
        uid="{page.uid}"
        as="images">

        <f:for each="{images}" as="image" iteration="index">
          <div style="background-image: url('{image.url}')" />
        </f:for>

</v:page.resources.fal>
```

Both don't output the image(s) in the frontend.

Also I cant find them in

```
<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>
```

I am using TYPO3 11.5.25 with the bootstrap package

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FilesProcessor` in your Typoscript.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/FilesProcessor.html

Here is an example for a footer menu, that shows title or image

```
        // Footer Menu
        40 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        40 {
            special = directory
            special.value = 672
            as = footerMenu
            titleField = nav_title // title
            dataProcessing {
                10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                10 {
                    references.fieldName = media
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the fluid template

```
        <f:for as="footerMenuItem" each="{footerMenu}" iteration="iterator">
            <f:if condition="{footerMenuItem.files.0}">
                <f:then>
                    <a href="{footerMenuItem.link}">
                        <f:image class="img-fluid" image="{footerMenuItem.files.0}" width="80"/>
                    </a>
                </f:then>
                <f:else>
                    <a href="{footerMenuItem.link}">{footerMenuItem.title}</a>
                </f:else>
            </f:if>
        </f:for>
```

Comment: Does this only work for tt_content elements? I am trying to use it for the page. This doesn't output anything for me.
Added:
page {
    dataProcessing.10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
    dataProcessing.10 {
        references.fieldName = media
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

this is a problem of vhs viewhelpers in one of the last versions. This viewhelper only works with a limit set. I have this problem in some typo3 instances and have to fix it by setting any limit.

```
<v:page.resources.fal
    table="pages"
    field="media"
limit="10"
    uid="{page.uid}" <--- sometimes this must be data.uid -->
    as="images">

<f:for each="{images}" as="image" iteration="index">
  <div style="background-image: url('{image.url}')" />
</f:for>

</v:page.resources.fal>
```